# Search and return values from nested dict (or from json file)

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have nested dictionaries created by importing json file (json.load), looking like this:

```
"124": {
    "vacancy_title": "Оператор линии",
    "vacancy_employer": "Промышленное  производство, Жуков",
    "vacancy_url": "https://www.rekadro.ru/vacancies/124/",
    "vacancy_city": "Обнинск"
},

"125": {
    "vacancy_title": "Консультант по подбору персонала",
    "vacancy_employer": "Кадровая компания \"Рекадро\", работа удаленно",
    "vacancy_url": "https://www.rekadro.ru/vacancies/125/",
    "vacancy_city": "Россия"
},
```

The JSON file is huge, and I need to find all the pieces of data where `vacancy_city == "somestring"`, `vacancy_city` is not a unique value.

What i try, is to do something like this:

```
import json


with open("vacancies_dict.json") as file:
    vacancies_dict = json.load(file)

city = "Санкт-Петербург"

for a,b in vacancies_dict.items():  #accessing keys
    for k in b.values():
        if k == city:
            for k, v in sorted(b.items())[-5:]:
                vacancy = f"{v['vacancy_title']}\n"\
                    f"{v['vacancy_employer']}\n"\
                    f"{v['vacancy_city']}\n"\
                    f"{(v['vacancy_title'],v['vacancy_url'])}\n"
```

It doesnt work, I understand that I do it the wrong way, I also know that masters can write a singleton with a regex (which sounds to me like magic).
Asking to help with finding a way to reach the result in a longer, but easier for "non programmer" understanding.

P.S. I was also looking to import from JSON directly the needed piece of data, using JSONSelect package, but it's deprecated (https://github.com/mwhooker/jsonselect)

Comment: Given your code sample, there seems to be a logic error in the lines ```for k in b.values()''', since the city seems to be defined by b['vacancy_city'] directly.  so you can eliminate the lines for``` k in b.values()``` and ```if k == city``` and replace with ```if b['vacancy city'] == city``` then the variables for vacancy can be derived directly from b['key'] where key is the variable to be included

Comment: It actually works. I dont know why i spent hours and hours. Everything geniues is simple, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This loop will work as a solution:

```
result = []
for i in range(0,126):
    if k[str(i)]['vacancy_city'] == "Bhopal":
        result.append(i)
```

The result list will have all the indices for the dictionary satisfying your condition.
Please change the variable names and range accordingly.